# Does AJV CLI support draft-2020?

Tags: ajv

AJV newbie here ...

I downloaded and installed AJV-CLI (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv-cli)

I created a JSON Schema that uses the `$anchor` keyword:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "num1": {
                    "$anchor": "five-two",
                    "anyOf": [
                        {"multipleOf": 5},
                        {"multipleOf": 2}
                    ]
        },
        "num2": {"$ref": "#five-two"}
    }
}
```

I created a simple instance:

```
{
    "num1": 2,
    "num2": 5
}
```

I opened a command window and typed:

```
ajv --spec=draft2020 --verbose=true --strict=true validate -s schema.json -d instance.json
```

That produced this error message:

```
error: strict mode: unknown keyword: "$anchor"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: a very convoluted answer is, yes and no.  It definitely supports some very basic JSON Schema fundamentals and most validation can be successful but, there are a few glaring items not supported, namely, dynamic referencing is not implemented correctly.  You can follow this 2 yr old outstanding issue for any new updates. 

https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv/issues/1573

There are a few more conformant implementations available at https://json-schema.org/implementations.html#validators

If you're looking for a JavaScript implementation, the closest to 100% conformance is Hyperjump